# Static Function Forcing Singleton Pattern?

Tags: c++, static, singleton

Here's the situation. I'm using a library (GLFW) that has some callback functions you set up to receive notifications on various stuff (error, window size changes, etc). These functions have to be static. To get this data back to the "non static" instance of the class I have been forced to make them a singleton. Is there a better / alternative method to handling forced static functions in a class?

Here is the best I've come up with so far:

```
//OpenGlTest.h
#pragma once

#include "glfw.h"

#pragma comment(lib,"opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"glfw3dll.lib")

class OpenGlTest
{
public:
    static OpenGlTest& GetInstance();

private:
    OpenGlTest(void);
    ~OpenGlTest(void);

public:

    void Initialize(void);

    static void stError(int iError, const char* sMessage);
    void onError(int iError, const char* sMessage);
};


//OpenGlTest.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "OpenGlTest.h"

OpenGlTest::OpenGlTest(void)
{ }

OpenGlTest::~OpenGlTest(void)
{ }

OpenGlTest& OpenGlTest::GetInstance()
{
    static OpenGlTest stOpenGlTest;
    return stOpenGlTest; //RETURN SINGLE INSTANCE
}

void OpenGlTest::Initialize( void )
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwSetErrorCallback(stError);
}

void OpenGlTest::onError( int iError, const char* sMessage )
{
    //YAY WE ARE NOT STATIC!
}

void OpenGlTest::stError( int iError, const char* sMessage )
{
    // BOO - THERE HAS TO BE ANOTHER WAY :(
    GetInstance().onError(iError, sMessage);
}
```

I also toyed with the idea of storing a pointer to each class created in a static vector - then calling a method on each class in the vector. But that just feels wrong too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a GLFW window, stuff the pointer to your class in it using `glfwSetWindowUserPointer`. In your static function, pull that pointer back out using `glfwGetWindowUserPointer`, cast it back to a pointer of the appropriate type, and call the appropriate non-static method.

Comment: Awesome - that will help with window related callbacks. But what about calls where there is no window handle (error / input)?

Comment: @cschear: GLFW appears to handle errors in a global manner. I don't know how severe its errors are, but if they're on the severe side of things, you might just want to print a message and exit. As for input, the documentation says there *is* a window pointer.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I have yet to start dealing with input. Thanks for your help - I would have never found that on my own.